# i am trying to connect to database using wamp but it throws file not found exception in android studio.How to solve this?

Tags: android, wamp

so i have configured the php files and my wamp tried to connect to data base but it throws an error i even kept an network security certificate but still throws the error.

Tried solutions
1. Added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true".
2.change the address to ipv4 address.
3.Added security file
Manifestxml:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config";
```

network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<debug-overrides>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="user" overridePins="true"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Error:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2/login.php
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.example.mysqltest.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:46)
        at com.example.mysqltest.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:19)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d285120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d2831f0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d285120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d2831f0)
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
Process 13292 terminated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://10.0.2.2/login.php

Instead using 10.0.2.2 Use your IPv4 address and add your Port number works for me though

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` and not to `10.0.0.2`
`10.0.0.2` is the localhost of the device, obviously the file is not on the device

you need to update your `/etc/hosts` file to reflect `localhost as 127.0.0.1` otherwise the device will just try to connect to itself